# Kotlin generics inheritance - Type mismatch

Tags: android, generics, inheritance, kotlin

I am trying to build a set of providers for realm objects. 
Here is an example structure I've tried to build:

Interface:

```
interface IDataProvider<out T : RealmObject> {
     fun getRealmObject(): T
}
```

Base provider class with companion function for typed provider instantiation:

```
open abstract class BaseProvider<out T : RealmObject> constructor(protected val context: Context?) : IDataProvider<T> {

     companion object {
         fun <T : RealmObject, E : BaseProvider<T>> create(context: Context?): E {        
        if (something) {
            return SomeChildProviderProvider(context)
        } else {
            throw TypeNotSupportedException()
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

And here is a child class:

```
class SomeChildProvider(context: Context?) : BaseProvider<ChildRealmModel>(context){
    override fun getRealmObject(): ChildRealmModel {
         throw UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented")
    }
}
```

Problem I have is on the line

```
return SomeChildProviderProvider(context)
```

> Type mismatch.
>   Required: E.
>   Found: SomeChildProvider.

I can't figure out why it does not see that E is actually SomeChildProvider.
Thank you.

P.S. I know that I can cast it to E, but in my opinion, it should not be needed in this situation. Maybe I am missing something obvious here or probably lack of Kotlin knowledge.

**UPDATE1:**
After the first answer, we have realized that code above does not make much sense since we have to define a type of returning provider and to pass it into create method. Initial idea was that create method returns some type which is BaseProvider subtype. Here are the changes I have made in order to support the initial idea:

IDataProvider

```
interface IDataProvider {
    fun execute(realm: Realm)
    fun createModel(realm: Realm): RealmObject
}
```

BaseProvider

```
 open abstract class BaseProvider constructor(protected val context: Context?) : IDataProvider {

    override fun execute(realm: Realm) {
        realm.executeTransaction { r ->
            createModel(r)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun create(context: Context?): IDataProvider {
            if (something) {
                return ChildProvider(context)
            } else {
                throw TypeNotSupportedException()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ChildProvider

```
class ChildProvider(context: Context?) : BaseProvider(context) {
    override fun createModel(realm: Realm): ChildRealmModel {
        var realmObject = realm.createObject(ChildRealmModel ::class.java)
        //object property initialization
        return realmObject
    }
}
```

UI call

```
BaseProvider.create(context).execute(realm)
```

Although, createModel method returns RealmObject, it's instance will be of ChildRealmModel. What I don't like about it is that we have to inspect instance type and cast into if we need exact model somewhere else.

Comment: Could you please be more specific what your are not satisfied about? I don't see where you  have to "inspect instance type and cast into if we need exact model".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not consistent.

In the function declaration you pledge to return `E`, which is a subtype of `BaseProvider<T>` and can be chosen by the user on the call site.

But in the implementation you return `SomeChildProviderProvider`, which is of course a subtype of `BaseProvider<T>`, but still can be totally unrelated to `E` which was chosen by the user.

An example:

```
class AnotherChildProvider : BaseProvider<ChildRealmModel>(context) {...}

val x = BaseProvider.create<ChildRealmModel, AnotherChildProvider>(context)
```

What is the type of `x`? According to the function signature, it must be `AnotherChildProvider`. But inside the function you return `SomeChildProviderProvider`, which CAN NOT be casted to `AnotherChildProviderProvider`.

Comment: You're right. I was tired enough to not realize that with create method I have to define the type of returning provider. However, my initial idea was to have a generic interface. Provider to implement that interface and some static method where I can decide which provider to instantiate. My solution is in UPDATE 1 in edited question, but I'm still not happy with it.